# decltype(auto) with multiple returning types using C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, auto, decltype

I installed the CTP-Nov2013-Compiler to get familiar/experiment with some C++14 features(learning by doing/reading) for VS 2013.
I tried something like a string to any POD-type converter without using generic methods which failed due to the error (cannot spell the correct error beacuse since today I made somehow Visual Studio to crash whenever I try to build the program[CTP bug?]) 'return type is not of the first return type'.

An example of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum EType{
    eInt,
    eBool,
    eFloat,
    eString
}

class Test
{
    Test();
    virtual ~Test(){}

    decltype(auto) SomeMethod(std::string texttoconvert, EType type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            //convert to the specific type by using the C++11 stoi* functions and return it (for the example I'm not checking for failure in the conversion)
            case eInt: return std::stoi(texttoconvert);
            break;
            case eFloat: return std::stof(texttoconvert);
            break;
            ...
            default:
            break;
        }
    }


int main()
{
    Test hugo;
    auto lAuto=hugo.SomeMethod("1.234", eFloat);
    cout<<lAuto<<endl; //should return a float
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is, is the error of logical kind (except not using try-catch-blocks for the `std::sto*` conversion) or is it a syntax error?

Another problem I have, is that I had to implement the method in the header file(else I got an error) and not in the .cpp file, is this a wanted/necessary feature like for template functions?

Comment: `decltype(auto)` is just a shorthand of `decltype(return_expression_which_could_be_too_long)`. So if there are multiple return expressions in your code, which one you meant? And how would the compiler know your intention?

Comment: Oh I see, well than I have misunderstood the use of 'decltype(auto)' and thought, that it is useful for a situation like above.
Could you also explain the reason why I had to implement the method with the 'decltype(auto)' return in the header file (the situation is not shown above)

Comment: @Nawaz is there an equivalent to noexcept? (`noexcept( auto )`)

Comment: @Serthy: I dont think that exists. What should that mean BTW?

Comment: @Nawaz I guess it would mean that the method is `noexcept` iff all statements in the method are `noexcept`. It may actually be useful in templates (or even as the default). But there is no such expression.

Comment: @StenSoft: Would that help anybody (compiler or programmer)? What is the default (i.e when you dont mention `noexcept` at all)?

Comment: `noexcept(auto)` could help in generic code, where some instantiations may be `noexcept` and others might not. An example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456801/is-there-an-automatic-noexcept-specifier

Comment: @Nawaz The defaults are quite complicated and are documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec#Potential_exceptions) but basically most methods without `noexcept` are `noexcept(false)`. Some code has different behavior depending on `noexcept`, eg. STL containers use much simpler code when items stored in them have `noexcept` constructors.

Comment: Don't you mean `SomeMethod("1.234", eFloat);`?

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for mentioning. Yes, that was meant, I've edited it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass compile-time information as a template parameter.

And type determining information must be compile-time information.

```
enum EType{
  eInt,
  eBool,
  eFloat,
  eString
};

template<EType type>
decltype(auto) convert(std::string texttoconvert);

template<>
decltype(auto) convert<eInt>(std::string texttoconvert) {
  return std::stoi(texttoconvert);
}
template<>
decltype(auto) convert<eFloat>(std::string texttoconvert) {
  return std::stof(texttoconvert);
}

struct Test {
  template<EType type>
  decltype(auto) SomeMethod(std::string texttoconvert) {
    return convert<type>(texttoconvert);
  }
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  float f = t.SomeMethod<eFloat>("3.14");
  std::cout << f << "\n";
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adadd9d0c3636c4b).

Answer (score 2):

It's semantic error. `auto` return type means the method has automatically deduced return type but the type is still one for the whole method, it cannot change based on the invoked `return` expression. Moreover, C++14 requires that all `return` expressions return the same type and forbids implicit conversions in this case.

Comment: It is *semantic* error, not *syntax*. All the syntax in the code are correct.