# Why isn't the noexcept specifier scoped within the declared method?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

Trying to design some exception-free classes, I have an inheritance structure similar to this, but I have found the **noexcept** specifier to be of little to no help when working with member functions as the specifier is not scoped as being within the function.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    Base() noexcept {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // error: 'Base::Base()' is protected
    Derived() noexcept(noexcept(Base{})) : Base{} {}

    // error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope
    Derived(int) noexcept(noexcept(foo())) {}

    // error: invalid use of 'this' at top level
    Derived(float) noexcept(noexcept(this->foo())) {}

    void foo() noexcept {}
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/wMoJNf)

Is this perhaps something that is being improved in C++17? Trying to search for this has yielded no relevant results. For now I've resigned to some very ugly (and possibly incorrect) attempts such as `noexcept(noexcept(static_cast<Derived*>(nullptr)->foo()))`, but this doesn't assist in the case of the base class constructor, which is protected.

Is it even currently possible to declare a noexcept specifier which references a protected base class method like this? [noexcept(auto)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456801/is-there-an-automatic-noexcept-specifier) *might* be relevant, but of course isn't possible yet. Have I overlooked anything else that would allow me to include this specifier, or do I simply have to omit it in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You can work around it by using an expression where the Base constructor is in scope like this:

```
struct test_base : public Base {};

Derived() noexcept(noexcept(test_base())) : Base() {}
```

I believe the reason you cannot use `Base()` directly is [related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2393495/459615).

> The way protected access specifier works, it allows the derived class
>   B to access the contents of an object of base class A only when that
>   object of class A is a subobject of class B. That means that the only
>   thing you can do in your code is to access the contents of A through
>   B: you can access the members of A through a pointer of type B * (or a
>   reference of type B &). But you cannot access the same members through
>   a pointer of type A * (or reference A &).

It's the same as if you had a member function like this:

```
void badfunc()
{
    B b;
}
```

You're trying to use `Base`'s constructor directly instead of going *through* `Derived`. When you initialize the base in the constructor initialization list, that is a special context that allows you to call the constructor because you're doing it as part of initializing `Derived`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that otherwise this code compiles correclty in clang. The other cases might be a bug in gcc, but I'm still studying the standard.

Comment: I've updated my response to hopefully shed some light on the inaccessibility of `Base()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is really multiple questions in one.

## About `this`...

From my understanding, the use of `this` is *supposed* to be completely superfluous but compiler support for C++11 is not entirely universal.  This should work, according to the C++11 standard:

```
struct Base {
    void func() noexcept;
};
struct Derived() {
    void func() noexcept(noexcept(Base::func())) {}
};
```

Note that `base_func()` is a non-static member function, but because it appears in an "unevaluated operand" it is okay.  From n3337 sec 4.1.1:

> An *id-expression* that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> ...
>
> - if that *id-expression* denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

However, some compilers do not support this.  You are then forced to use `std::declval`:

```
#include <utility>
struct Base {
    void func() noexcept;
};
struct Derived() {
    void func() noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<Base>().func())) {}
};
```

## About accessibility...

I read through the relevant parts of the standard about "unevaluated operands" and "member access control" and I have come to the conclusion that the standard is a bit ambiguous.  It mentions that a `protected` name can be *used* only by members, friends, and derived classes.  The question is whether unevaluated operands "use" the member names which appear in them.  They certainly don't *odr-use* the member names, and can even use member names if no definition is provided, and this kind of ambiguity is exactly why the term "odr-use" even exists!  For example,

```
int f(); // No definition anywhere in program
int x = sizeof(f()); // Completely valid, even without definition of f

struct X {
    X() = delete; // Cannot use this constructor
};
int xsize = sizeof(X{}); // Completely valid
```

Even though it is somewhat unclear, I have a hard time imagining that the C++ committee could have intended to let you use *deleted* member functions in unevaluated operands but not inaccessible member functions.  However, I am not certain.

Note that the above code compiles without error both with GCC and Clang.  However, the following code is does not:

```
class X {
    X(){}
};
class Y {
    Y() = delete;
};
bool xokay = noexcept(X{}); // Error!
bool yokay = noexcept(Y{}); // Ok
```

Both GCC and Clang accept Y but not X, which seems a bit *weird* to say the least.  The following code is accepted by Clang but not GCC, and using `std::declval` does not help:

```
class Base {
protected:
    void func();
};
class Derived : public Base {
    // Clang accepts this, GCC does not.
    void func2() noexcept(noexcept(Base::func())) {}
};
```

What a mess.

### Conclusions

The conclusion here is that it seems that there is plenty of inconsistency to go around, and plenty of gaps between current compilers and the C++11 specs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant to say `std::declval` instead of `std::decltype`.