# How to correctly deduce noexcept-ness of a function?

Tags: c++, c++17, noexcept, copy-elision

In a generic context, it is quite often we write something like

```
return_type f(arg_type1 arg1, ...)
  noexcept(noexcept(statement_1) && noexcept(statement_2) && ... && noexcept(statement_n))
{
  statement_1;
  statement_2;
  ...
  statement_n;
}
```

When a `statement_k` is a return statement, things aren't so simple. It is just impossible to write `noexcept(return expr)`. Instead, I should understand what's going on when we say `return expr` and break down it into several `noexcept(something)`'s. But it seems quite nontrivial.

I've come up with something like the following algorithm:

1. If `return_type` is a reference type, then of course `noexcept(expr)` suffices.
2. If `return_type` is not a reference type but if `return expr` is a situation where guaranteed copy elision happens then again `noexcept(expr)` suffices.
3. Otherwise, `noexcept(expr) && std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<return_type>::value && std::is_nothrow_destructible<return_type>::value`.

Is it right? Or is there any simpler way? The case 1 would be subsumed as a special case of case 3, but how about case 2 and 3?

Comment: You want a `noexcept(auto)` as we have for `decltype`.

Comment: Related to: [is-there-an-automatic-noexcept-specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456801/is-there-an-automatic-noexcept-specifier)

Comment: @Jarod42 AFAIK, the author of that proposal withdrew it.... Too bad

Comment: @JunekeyJeon: There is no function that needs to be correctly `noexcept` *that badly*. It's much better to just not care in such cases. You're setting yourself up for a maintenance nightmare for something that, ultimately, just doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Case 3 is incorrect if `decltype(expr)` is not the same as `return_type`, ie there is a type conversion occurring in the expression

Comment: @Eric Thanks for pointing it out. How about something like ````noexcept(return_type{ expr })````?