# noexcept(auto) to automatically deduce if a function can be declared noexcept

Tags: c++

*Disclaimer: since this is likely to become an opinion based topic I would like to focus more on the factual side of things.*

## Prologue

In C++, we have the `noexcept` specifier to declare that a function may (or may not) throw an expection. Furthermore, we have the `noexcept` operator that tells us whether an expression can throw an exception or not.

Especially in TMP it can be a pain to specify whether a function can or cannot throw. Take [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) for example:

```
template< class F, class... Args>
constexpr std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...> invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) noexcept(noexcept(std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<F, Args...>));
```

It even needs a type trait for what basically results in:

```
auto invoke(F f, Args... args) noexcept(noexcept(f(args...)))
{
    return f(args...);
}
```

Interestingly enough, the MSVC implementation even reverses the relationship between `std::invoke` and `std::is_nothrow_invocable`, basically doing

```
std::is_nothrow_invocable = noexcept(std::invoke(F, Args...))
```

and having a myriad of overloads for `std::invoke`. Lets take a look at the case that handles a normal function call (e.g. lambda or namespace function):

```
template <class _Callable, class... _Types>
CONSTEXPR auto _CONCAT(NAME_PREFIX, invoke)(_Callable && _Obj, _Types && ... _Args)
noexcept(noexcept(_CONCAT(NAME_PREFIX, _Invoker) < _Callable, _Types... > ::_Call(_STD forward<_Callable>(_Obj), _STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...))) 
-> decltype(_CONCAT(NAME_PREFIX, _Invoker) < _Callable, _Types... > ::_Call(_STD forward<_Callable>(_Obj), _STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...)) /* INVOKE a callable object */
{
    return _CONCAT(NAME_PREFIX, _Invoker)<_Callable, _Types...>::_Call(_STD forward<_Callable>(_Obj), _STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
}
```

There are a lot of macros involved here but the gist of it is, that the function body has to be repeated 3 times:

1. to accurately declare `noexcept`
2. to specify the return type (not sure why it's done that way, maybe to be explicit about it)
3. the function body itself

## Proposal

Now lets assume we extented the `noexcept` specifier with the following syntax:

```
noexcept(auto)
```

The behavior is simple: resolve to `noexcept(true)` if, and only if, `noexcept(expr)` evaluates to `true` for each expression `expr` in the function's body. Otherwise `noexcept(false)`.

I'm not that familiar with the standard so I'm not sure if the term *expression* is too loosely here.

The pseudo implementation above

```
auto invoke(F f, Args... args) noexcept(noexcept(f(args...)))
{
    return f(args...);
}
```

would then become

```
auto invoke(F f, Args... args) noexcept(auto)
{
    return f(args...);
}
```

## Epilogue

I've only used `std::invoke` as an example here but I'm certain there are more functions in the standard library (and in the wild) that could benefit from such a feature, especially in TMP.

Now to the questions:

1. I don't see any compatibility issues if such a feature was added but I'm just a dude, so are there any problems in this regard?
2. What are the caveats/disadvantages of this proposal?
3. (optional) Where else would this come in handy within the standard library?

My last question is about compiler optimizations. After reading [When should I really use noexcept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787766/when-should-i-really-use-noexcept) (especially the second answer) I was wondering what the compiler does if we declare a function `noexcept` and throw inside that function. I know the standard requires a call to `std::terminate` in this case, but how does a compiler implement this? I assume the compiler does something like this (going back to the `std::invoke` example):

```
auto invoke(F f, Args... args) noexcept(noexcept(f(args...)))
{
    try
    {
       return f(args...);
    }
    catch
    {
        std::terminate();
    }
}
```

I'm far from beeing an expert on optimizations so I don't know how much the compiler optimizes, but I assume it's a lot. Nevertheless, the compiler is only required to do that handling because we could have lied when declaring our function `noexcept`. However, if we let the compiler deduce the `noexcept`ness it knows for certain and therefore doesn't need to catch anything. On the other hand, I assume the compiler already does that regardless. So

4. Would this proposal affect performance?

Comment: You can't detect at compile time whether a function will throw an exception. It may call into pre-compiled library code that the compiler cannot see, which may or may not throw. Which means that your function may or may not throw.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's true, but what the compiler can do is check if a function is declared `noexcept` (since it is part of the function type). I'm not trying (or claiming) to detect if a function may or may not throw. One could call my idea _perfect forwarding of `noexcept`_.

Comment: Looks like a sound idea. If all called functions are declared `noexcept` and I don't throw explicitly, this function should also be `noexcept`.

Comment: Does the answer to the question [Is there an automatic noexcept specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456801/is-there-an-automatic-noexcept-specifier) answer your question?

Comment: @L.F. lol even the same syntax. Thanks.