# Simplify noexcept specifier + trailing return type + function body

Tags: c++

Imagine writing some generic code:

```cpp
template<class...Args>
auto do_something(Args&&...args)
        noexcept(noexcept(detail::do_something(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
        -> decltype(detail::do_something(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return detail::do_something(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I have to repeat the long expression of `detail::do_something(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` three times.

`noexcept` specifier is needed to propagate `noexcept`-ness.

Trailing return type is needed because many standard type traits and concepts (e.g. `invocable`-families) need to know the return type in immediate context.

I know that this could be worked around by macros. But is there any C++ way to simplify it or any existing work that might help to simplify it in the future?

For example, there's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30727718/13456180) written in 2015 that mentioned a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4473) introducing `noexcept(auto)` but still being at status of *"Do we think the valid and reasonable uses of noexcept(auto) are important enough that we should standardize it?"*.

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no language support for this in the standard other than using macro. However, you can use [`BOOST_HOF_RETURNS`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/returns.html) from Boost.HOF to avoid duplicating expressions

```
#include <boost/hof/returns.hpp>

namespace detail {
  template<class...Args>
  decltype(auto) do_something(Args&&...args);
};

template<class...Args>
auto do_something(Args&&...args)
  BOOST_HOF_RETURNS(
    detail::do_something(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v3EM3YfEx)

Comment: yep, I known macro is an approach.  But it has drawback that trailing `requires` clause and specifiers like `override` and `final` cannot be used.

Comment: Yep, and unfortunately, macros are also the *only* simple way at the moment.