# Why can I not retrieve the index of a variant and use that to get its content?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I'm trying to access the content of a variant. I don't know what's in there, but thankfully, the variant does. So I thought I'll just ask the variant what index it is on and then use that index to `std::get` its content.

But this does not compile:

```
#include <variant>

int main()
{
  std::variant<int, float, char> var { 42.0F };

  const std::size_t idx = var.index();

  auto res = std::get<idx>(var);

  return 0;
}
```

The error happens in the `std::get` call:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘get<idx>(std::variant<int, float, char>&)’
   auto res = std::get<idx>(var);
                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/variant:37,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/utility:216:5: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> constexpr typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)’
     get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>& __in) noexcept
     ^~~
/usr/include/c++/8/utility:216:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:9:31: error: the value of ‘idx’ is not usable in a constant expression
   auto res = std::get<idx>(var);
                               ^
main.cpp:7:15: note: ‘std::size_t idx’ is not const
   std::size_t idx = var.index();
               ^~~
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I suspect the error you are getting is related to the index not being a constant expression. Please post the compiler error messages so we can provide meaningful help.

Comment: Missing constexpr?

Comment: Whoops! You talked about an error, but you didn't post the exact text of the error.

Comment: Sorry for the omission, I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, you cannot.

You wrote:

> I don't know what's in there, but thankfully, the variant does

... but only at run-time, not at compile-time.
And that means your `idx` value is not compile-time.
And *that* means you can't use `get<idx>()` directly.

Something you could do is have a switch statement; ugly, but it would work:

```
switch(idx) {
case 0: { /* code which knows at compile time that idx is 0 */ } break;
case 1: { /* code which knows at compile time that idx is 1 */ } break;
// etc. etc.
}
```

This is rather ugly however. As comments suggest, you might as well `std::visit()` (which is not very different from the code above, except using variadic template arguments instead of being this explicit) and avoid the switch altogether. For other index-based approaches (not specific to `std::variant`), see:

[Idiom for simulating run-time numeric template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914655/idiom-for-simulating-run-time-numeric-template-parameters)

Comment: @Caleth: Yes. Edited.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler needs to know the value of `idx` at compilation time for `std::get<idx>()` to work, because it is being used as a template argument.

First option: If the code is meant to run at compile time, then make everything `constexpr`:

```
constexpr std::variant<int, float, char> var { 42.0f };

constexpr std::size_t idx = var.index();

constexpr auto res = std::get<idx>(var);
```

This works because `std::variant` is `constexpr` friendly (its constructors and methods are all `constexpr`).

Second option: If the code is not meant to run at compile time, which is likely the case, the compiler cannot deduce at compile time the type of `res`, because it could be three different things (`int`, `float` or `char`). C++ is a statically-typed language, and the compiler must be able to deduce the type of `auto res = ...` from the expression that follows (i.e. it must always be the same type).

You can use `std::get<T>`, with the type instead of an index, if you already know what it will be:

```
std::variant<int, float, char> var { 42.0f }; // chooses float

auto res = std::get<float>(var);
```

In general, use `std::holds_alternative` to check if the variant is holding each of the given types, and handle them separately:

```
std::variant<int, float, char> var { 42.0f };

if (std::holds_alternative<int>(var)) {
    auto int_res = std::get<int>(var); // int&
    // ...
} else if (std::holds_alternative<float>(var)) {
    auto float_res = std::get<float>(var); // float&
    // ...
} else {
    auto char_res = std::get<char>(var); // char&
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively you can use `std::visit`. This is slightly more complicated: you can use a lambda/templated function that is type-agnostic and works for all of the variant's types, or pass a functor with an overloaded call operator:

```
std::variant<int, float, char> var { 42.0f };

std::size_t idx = var.index();

std::visit([](auto&& val) {
    // use val, which may be int&, float& or char&
}, var);
```

See [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) for details and examples.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `std::get<idx>(var);` require (for `idx`) a compile time known value.

So a `constexpr` value

```
// VVVVVVVVV
   constexpr std::size_t idx = var.index();
```

But to initialize `idx` as `constexpr`, also `var` had to be `constexpr`

```
// VVVVVVVVV
   constexpr std::variant<int, float, char> var { 42.0F };
```

Comment: …And a constexpr variant isn’t very variant.

Comment: @DavisHerring - That is also true.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises from templates being instantiated at compile-time while the index you are getting is calculated at run-time. Similarly, C++ types are also defined at compile-time so even with the `auto` declaration, `res` must have a concrete type for the program to be well-formed. This means that even without the restriction on the template, what you are trying to do is inherently impossible for non-constant expression `std::variant`s. How would one work around this?

Firstly, if your variant is indeed a constant expression, the code compiles and works as expected

```cpp
#include <variant>

int main()
{
  constexpr std::variant<int, float, char> var { 42.0f };

  constexpr std::size_t idx = var.index();

  auto res = std::get<idx>(var);

  return 0;
}
```

Otherwise you will have to use some manual branching mechanism

```cpp
if (idx == 0) {
    // Now 'auto' will have a concrete type which I've explicitly used
    int value == std::get<0>(var);
}
```

You could define these branches using the visitor pattern, see [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Answer (score 1):

This is inherently impossible in C++’s model; consider

```
template<class T> void f(T);
void g(std::variant<int,double> v) {
  auto x=std::get<v.index()>(v);
  f(x);
}
```

Which `f` is being called, `f<int>` or `f<double>`?  If it’s “both”, that means that `g` contains a branch (which it doesn’t), or that there are two versions of `g` (which just pushes the problem onto its caller).  And think about `f(T,U,V,W)`—where does the compiler stop?

There is actually a [proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1609r2.html) for a JIT for C++ that would allow things like this by compiling those additional versions of `f` when they’re called, but it’s very early.

Comment: I suppose it will be usefull if in case variant defined as <int16_t, int32_t, double> variant will try to cast value at less size common type by default, and if it is impossible then cast to more heavy size type. For example, in "v = 0" definition it will be int16_t by default and get zero index, when asking index. And also this index should be available in compile time becouse zero was actually integral literal.