# Data structure of constexpr values

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

Suppose you have `std::tuple` and a function, which modifies on of its values based on the type.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Ts...>
void modify(std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple, const T& value)
{
    std::get<T>(tuple) = value;
}
```

Now suppose, you want to *log* those function calls, i.e. remember the order of modification of values in the tuple. Here is simple mechanism that does that.

```cpp
void log(std::size_t index)
{
    static std::vector<std::size_t> logged_indexes;
    logged_indexes.push_back(index)
}
```

with following helper

```cpp
// counts until T is same as N'th type of Tuple
template<typename Tuple, typename T, std::size_t N>
struct tuple_type_index_impl;

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct tuple_type_index_impl<std::tuple<>, T, N>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = N;
};

template<typename First, typename... Rest, typename T, std::size_t N>
struct tuple_type_index_impl<std::tuple<First, Rest...>, T, N>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = std::is_same<First, T>::value
        ? N
        : tuple_type_index_impl<std::tuple<Rest...>, T, N + 1>::value;
};

// helper variable
template<typename Tuple, Typename T>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_type_index_v = typename tuple_type_index_impl<Tuple, T, 0>::value;
```

we can have this usage

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Ts...>
void modify(std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple, const T& value)
{
    std::get<T>(tuple) = value;
    log(tuple_type_index_v<std::tuple<Ts...>, T>);
}
```

Which is fine for logging purposes. But suppose you would have to, based on the index, access the tuple again. We can *convert* runtime index to constexpr using a switch

```cpp
switch (value)
{
case 0: return std::get<0>(tuple);
case 1: return std::get<1>(tuple);
...
}
```

which can be compiler generated. But is it really the best we can do? In call to log, the `index` is still constexpr, so we could move that to template parameter.

```cpp
template<std::size_t index>
void log()
{
    static std::vector<std::size_t> logged_indexes;
    logged_indexes.push_back(index);
}
```

But that won't help, since we are still passing it to the vector. We could (?) sort of build `std::index_sequence`, but we would eventually run out of template parameters. Part of me thinks that this can't be done, but the other opposes, since `index` is constexpr. Is it possible to develop some kind of `std::vector<constexpr std::size_t>`?

Comment: Is this switch or its replacement meant to be inside the logging function? e.g. you want to log the value as well as the index?

Comment: @jwimberley I don't mind the values, just indexes of accessed values. The switch is *generated* by the compiler using similar approach as showed for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997271/c11-way-to-index-tuple-at-runtime-without-using-switch).

Comment: You can change `tuple_type_index_v` to return `std::integral_constant`, so you still have compile time value.

Comment: @Jarod42 `tuple_type_index_v` is compile time value.

Comment: Do you want retrieve tuple element from vector content, or from `log` function ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't understand the question

Comment: Not sure what you want, I modified you sample: [Demo](https://ideone.com/2ciE2A)

Comment: @Jarod42 Idea is to store accessed indexes (as you do in `log`) and then retrieve them back, but as compile time constants, so that they can be passed directly to `std::get<index>` without need of that switch (finding correct compile time index based on runtime index is O(n))

Comment: The switch can be done/implemented in `O(1)`. And you can even do the array yourself to guaranty the `O(1)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you post an answer? I am using recursive visitor pattern as show in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997271/c11-way-to-index-tuple-at-runtime-without-using-switch) and I think it's O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform your `switch` to "direct" call, you may do something like:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void print(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t, std::size_t index)
{
    if (sizeof...(Ts) < index) {
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid index");
    }
    using func_t = void (*)(const std::tuple<Ts...>&);
    func_t fs[] = { (+[](const std::tuple<Ts...>& t){
             std::cout << std::get<Ts>(t) << std::endl;
        })...
        // gcc dislikes that lambda,
        // but you can create template function instead
    };

    fs[index](t);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fe143381376f8fc)

Comment: I actually tested it and the performance is same as with switch, so compiler can somehow optimize that.