# Cpp Tuple use get with a variable

Tags: c++, tuples, containers

So, i was trying to use std::get with a variable to search a certain position of a tuple. But for my surprise i cannot access any position using a tuple.
Do you guys know why and how to overcome this problem? I need a lot of a container that gives me different types.

I will put my code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>



struct MyStruct
{
    std::tuple<int, float> t;
    int pos;
} myStruct;

int main()
{
    MyStruct* var = new MyStruct();
    var->t = std::make_tuple(1,2.33);
    var->pos = 1;
    
    std::get<1>(var->t); //this works
    std::get<var->pos>(var->t); //this doesn't work but i need to search "dynamically"
}
```

best regards!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194227/how-to-get-the-i-th-element-from-an-stdtuple-when-i-isnt-know-at-compile-time

Comment: Are you sure that you want a tuple or perhaps a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: What can you do if you you can get a specific element from a tuple which has different type? Can you show any real world use case please!

Comment: A tuple that you can access with a variable is spelled `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are resolved at compile time, so you cannot use a variable whose value is not known until runtime to access the tuple with `get`. If you are using `C++17` an alternative could be to use something like `std::vector<std::any>` (suggested reading: [std::any: How, when, and why](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stdany-how-when-and-why/)).

### Related Questions:

- [C++11 way to index tuple at runtime without using switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28997271/2546289)
- [access tuple elements by index c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293382/access-tuple-elements-by-index-c11)